# Multilevel drilldown in piechart

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, amcharts, multi-level, drilldown

I am working on a project where i need to show data in a pie chart.
I need multilevel drill down in it i.e. about 5-6 levels.

Can anyone please share a sample code of how to do it?
I tried doing it in Highcharts as well as Amcharts.

But couldn't figure out how to get it done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible to do in Highcharts - simple example with multiple levels: http://jsfiddle.net/poo0au8z/. What have you tried? Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in amcharts you might use related set of concentric donut charts with center looking like pie and outer looking like concentric circles.  Search amcharts for nested donut charts.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.